# Can someone please verify if my code ist within the python and object-oriented programming "standards"?

Tags: python, oop

I am currently learning both Java and Python, but i'm more used to program using Java. Therefore, i tend to program using Python as if i'm programming using Java: i'm not used to the "philosophy" of the language.
Yesterday, i was doing the following exercise:

> Create an algorithm, which calculates the amount of taxes an employee must pay. The amount of taxes they must pay is based on the following table (i needed to format the table as code, otherwise this website won't let me post the question):

```
# (R$ stands for Real - the brazilian currency)
# salary < R$ 1000,00 - 5% of taxes
# R$ 1000,00 <= salary < R$ 2000,00 - 10% of taxes
# R$ 2000,00 <= salary < R$ 4000,00 - 15% of taxes
# R$ 4000,00 <= salary  - 20% of taxes
```

As you can see, it's not a difficult exercise. In fact, it's a simple programming logic exercise. I tried to do it object-oriented, and created the following code in Python:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Employee:

    def __init__(self):
        self.salary = Decimal('0')
        self._taxValue = Decimal('0')

    @property
    def salary(self):
        return self.salary

    @salary.setter
    def salary(self, value):

        if Decimal('0') <= value < Decimal('1000'):
            self._taxValue = value * Decimal('0.05')
        elif Decimal('1000') <= value < Decimal('2000'):
            self._taxValue = value * Decimal('0.1')
        elif Decimal('2000') <= value < Decimal('4000'):
            self._taxValue = value * Decimal('0.15')
        elif Decimal('4000') <= value:
            self._taxValue = value * Decimal('0.2')
        else:
            raise Exception()
        self._salary = value


    def calculateTaxes(self):
        while True:
            try:
                employeeSalary = input("Type the employee's salary:")
                employeeSalary = Decimal(employeeSalary)
                self.salary = employeeSalary
                break
            except:
                print("You've typed a invalid salary! Try again.")

        print(f'The value of taxes to be paid is R$ {self._taxValue}')

employee = Employee()
employee.calculateTaxes()
```

The question is: i'm still learning to do object-oriented codes and i'm also used to program using Java. Can someone please verify if the code is within the "Python" and "object-oriented" standards (i don't know how to call that) and let me know if i made any mistakes? The code works, which is a good start, but i'm not sure if it's easily readable and if it's within these standards.

Comment: Mabe better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: in the `__init__` it should be `self._salary`. And I would raise a `ValueError` to be more specific.

Comment: @user_na thank you, i didn't know codereview.stackexchange.com existed, i'll use it next time

but i don't get it... why should it be `self._salary` in the `__init__` instead of `self.salary`? i would thank you a lot if you could explain me the exact meaning of _ before an attribute, i searched it but i didn't understand.
and thank you a lot i'll use your tip to raise a ValueError

Answer (score 0):

Your class has a proplem with the getter. If you call

```
employee = Employee()
employee.salary
```

your python will crash. The reason has to do with the difference of `_salary` and `salary`. The way you set it up, you have one internal (private) class variable `_salary` to which you save the actual value. (Note in python there is no real private value as there is in Java).
Then you have `salary` which is a setter and a getter funtion to access the value of `_salary`.

This you can see, e.g. by looking at class instance with `dir`:

```
>>> print(dir(employee))
[...,'_salary', '_taxValue', 'calculateTaxes', 'salary']
```

When you look at your getter, it is defined as:

```
@property
def salary(self):
    return self.salary
```

So it will actually return itself over and over again until your python crashes. What you acually wanted to do is

```
@property
def salary(self):
    return self._salary
```

This way the internal value of `_salay` will be returned.

Regarding my comment to the `__init__`. If you use `self.salary` you are writing via the setter. If you use `self._salary` you directly writing to the private variable. So it doesn't really matter, but if you are setting `_salary` it's your duty to also set `_taxValue`, where as `salary` will automatically set it inside the setter.

I would say if you use `self.salary` you should in-fact remove the setting of `_taxValue` in the init. The reason is, that if you ever want to do something like this:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.salary = Decimal(value)
    #self._taxValue = Decimal('0')
```

The commented out line will overwrite the correct value of `_taxValue`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I can't cast a vote, because i don't have enough reputation, but i'll do this as soon as i have reputation